# I can't append rows into table using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I can't add rows into table using jQuery. I want to insert rows into table with id myTable

My code is

```
  <script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript">
  </script>
  <script language="javascript">
  $('#covered').on('change', function () {
  var v = this.value;
  for (var i = 0; i < v; i++) {
    $('#myTable').append('<tr><td>new added row' + i + '</td><td> col 2</td></tr>');
    }
   });
  </script>

<table id='myTable'>
<tr>
    <td>col 1</td>
    <td>col 2</td>
</tr>
</table>
<select name="covered" id="covered">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: You need a document ready event handler.

Comment: what error you getting ?

Answer (score 1):

Works fine (even though you add two rows at a time) if you add document ready.

```
$(document).ready(function (){

     $('#covered').on('change', function () {
  var v = this.value;
  for (var i = 0; i < v; i++) {
    $('#myTable').append('<tr><td>new added row' + i + '</td><td> col 2</td></tr>');
    }
   });
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mQS8N/7/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialise jquery:

```
$(function(){
   // code here
});
```

and code will work:

http://jsfiddle.net/2UvFT/

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap your code inside **[DOM ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)** handler `$(document).ready(function() {...});` or shorter form `$(function(){...});` to make sure all of your DOM elements have been loaded properly before executing your jQuery code:

```
$(function() {
    $('#covered').on('change', function () {
        var v = this.value;
        for (var i = 0; i < v; i++) {
            $('#myTable').append('<tr><td>new added row' + i + '</td><td> col 2</td></tr>');
        }
     });
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/L8QxT/)**

Answer (score 0):

Write the code in DOM ready:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#covered').on('change', function () {
  var v = this.value;
  for (var i = 0; i < v; i++) {
    $('#myTable').append('<tr><td>new added row' + i + '</td><td> col 2</td></tr>');
   }
});});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UvAdm/)**

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap your code within doc ready block:

```
$(function(){
    $('#covered').on('change', function () {
       var v = this.value;
       for (var i = 0; i < v; i++) {
           $('#myTable').append('<tr><......</td></tr>');
       }
    });
});
```

#### [Demo with doc ready](http://jsfiddle.net/Puyuf/1/)

---

And there is one more way if you delegate your event to `document` then doc ready block is not needed but i will not recommend you to do it because it is very slow in performance wise.

```
    $(document).on('change', '#covered', function () {
       var v = this.value;
       for (var i = 0; i < v; i++) {
           $('#myTable').append('<tr><......</td></tr>');
       }
    });
```

#### [Demo with delagated @ document](http://jsfiddle.net/Puyuf/)